# Proving $(\forall n \in N)[2n|n^2]$ is false

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

This is false : $(\forall n \in N)[2n|n^2]$ but how can be proved ?

$b|a$ if and only if $ \exists q[a=bq] , b \neq 0 $

This is my proof :

To prove $(\forall n \in N)[2n|n^2]$ is false take $n=3$

So $2(3)|3^2$ = $6/9$ = $2/3$ which is not an integer.

---

To prove $(\forall n \in N)[2n|n^2]$ by contradiction , is this correct :

To prove a statement is false prove it's negation is true.

Negating $(\forall n \in N)[2n|n^2]$

= $\neg(\forall n \in N)[2n|n^2]$

Negating a $\forall$ becomes $\exists$ , Negating a $\exists$ becomes $\forall$

= $(\exists n \forall N)[2n|n^2]$

So now need to prove $(\exists n \forall N)[2n|n^2]$ is true

Is $2(3)|3^2$ = $6/9$ = $2/3$ now a contradiction ?

Comment: As you remarked "to prove $(\forall n \in \mathbb{N})[2n|n^2]$ is false take $n=3$", so this proves that $$(\exists n \in \mathbb{N})\overline{[2n|n^2]}$$ is true and that suffices !

Comment: Your first proof is not right, as you interpret $a|b$ incorrectly. In your second attempt, the negation does not cause another quantifier. You just move the negetation across the universal, change that t9o existential, finally put negation on statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula $(\forall n \in N)[2n|n^2]$ is false if $\exists n\in N$ such that $[2n\not| n^2]$. In other words, the former formula is false when $\exists n\in N[n\not|n^2]$ is true.